# WSO2 EI Sequence failing when calling a Data Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Running WSO2 EI 6.2.0

My sequence is very simple:

1. Receive 1 parameter (mac) from initial request
2. Call a DS to extract a second parameter (time_hour)
3. Call a DS with both parameters (mac) and (time_hour)

When calling both DS manually, it works perfectly.

When calling the second DS through ESB I get a strange error.

The sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="somesq" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="$url:mac" name="uri.var.mac" scope="default"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="mac" scope="default" type="STRING" value="get-property('uri.var.mac')"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://somedomain.internal.com/someservice?var={uri.var.mac}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="body"/>
        <target action="replace" property="payload" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('payload')" name="bbb" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <property expression="$ctx:payload//ns2:hour" name="time_hour"
        scope="default" type="STRING"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
    <header action="remove" name="Content-Type" scope="transport"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.mac')" name="mac" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('time_hour')"
            name="time_hour" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://somedomain.internal.com/someservice?var={uri.var.mac}&amp;hour={time_hour}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="xxx" value="FIM"/>
    </log>
    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

I try to log the parameters before calling the DS and they are correctly printed, but when I use it in the DS Call, the `hour={time_hour}` parameter is empty.

The output and error:

```
(...)
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-12-05 12:24:02,562]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  mac = 000000000000 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-12-05 12:24:02,562]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  time_hour = 2018-12-03T11:00:00.000+00:00 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-12-05 12:24:02,569] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver}
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: Error processing parameter - hour, Error - DS Fault Message: Empty string or null value was found as timeStamp.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Empty string or null value was found as timeStamp.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR


DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: some_seq
Location: /some_seq.dbs
Description: Some Seq
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: somesq
Current Params: {hour=, mac=000000000000}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error processing parameter - hour, Error - DS Fault Message: Empty string or null value was found as timeStamp.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
(...)
```

Anyone knows how to correctly reference the time_hour parameter to the data services in the ESB Sequence?

**Explanation of why the variable time_hour was not being evaluated**

From [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/HTTP+Endpoint):

> The URI templates allow a RESTful URI to contain variables that can be
> populated during mediation runtime using property values whose names
> have the **"uri.var" prefix**.

**The Final Sequence that is working based on Jan's response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="some_seq" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="$url:mac" name="uri.var.mac" scope="default"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://somedomain.internal.com/someservice?var=={uri.var.mac}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="body"/>
        <target action="replace" property="payload" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
    <property expression="$ctx:payload//ns2:hour"
        name="uri.var.time_hour" scope="default" type="STRING"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
    <header action="remove" name="Content-Type" scope="transport"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://somedomain.internal.com/someservice?var=={uri.var.mac}&amp;hour={uri.var.time_hour}"/>
            <property name="time_h" value="{time_hour}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs 'uri.var' as variable name for it to be usable as uri-template variable.

So create a property with the current time. (I'm surprised btw that 'time_hour' works for you, in my case I used SYSTEM_DATE, time_hour reverts to 'null' )

```
<property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE')" name="uri.var.time_hour"/>
```

and use that in your endpoint.

Comment: I reached the uri.var conclusion 5 minutes ago :) because I thought it was strange the MAC was working but time_hour wasn't. time_hour comes from an enriched based property from a previous call